# Erro ao instanciar um objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Quando vou instanciar o objeto `Vendedor` aparece esse erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Vendedor.<init>(Vendedor.java:9)
```

Gostaria de saber o que significa e como resolvo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Significa que ocorreu um `NullPointerException` na linha 9 do arquivo Vendedor.java

**Solução:**

Não cause um `NullPointerException` :-)

*Dica:
qualquerVariavel.qualquerCoisa() causa NullPointerException se qualquerVariavel for null.*

Comment: marcus, seria bom se pudesse fornecer mais informações em sua resposta e deixá-la mais rica.

Comment: Acredito que uma explicação sobre **o que é** uma exceção de ponteiro nulo, bem como uma sugestão de como encontrar por conta própria o trecho de código que possa estar a provocá-la, tornariam a resposta aceitável.

Comment: Bem, a resposta foi curta e grossa, mas está tudo ali: indiquei a linha 9 (que eu não sei o que tem, pois não foi postado o código), e um exemplo de uma situação que causa a exceção. Só não coloquei muita explicação teórica.

Answer (score 2):

A exceção [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) é lançada quando o programa tenta utilizar a referência de um objeto com o valor nulo. Veja um exemplo:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String foo = null;
    System.out.println(foo.toString()); // NullPointerException será lançada
}
```